# Connect to a wifi through code

Tags: wifi, brute-force, software, c++, batch

Is there any way a person could write a software using for example C++ to connect to a wifi completely by using code?

Comment: This is not an InfoSec question but a programming one. You also do not specify your scope because every single connection to wifi that has ever been performed has been done through code.